# Why to ignore the constants in computing the running time complexity of an Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Can someone explain the reason behind ignoring the constants in computing the running time complexity of an Algorithm please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When analysing time complexity constants are difficult and irrelevant to calculate.

On some architecture addition might take twice as long as multiplication, so now we have to go through the algorithm and calculate the number of additions we make, and the number of multiplications we make in order to get an accurate runtime analysis. Not pretty!

More importantly, even if that is true now, at some point in the future, or on another slightly different architecture, that constant may be different, so the runtime would vary between architectures. So now my algorithm has more than one runtime? One for now on this architecture, and another for another architecture, and each of those may change in the future... Again, not pretty.

In a world where the capabilities of computing change all the time, twice the CPU capabilities tomorrow, four times the memory in a week, etc. there is little relevance to constant factors. This isn't the case if we need to quantify real-life runtime, but when we are analysing the complexity of an algorithm in general, not the complexity of a solution in a specific environment it is the case.

Also, and probably most importantly, the constant factors are not a good measure of the complexity of the problem, and at the end of the day we are trying to measure complexity. An algorithm that is of a specific complexity class, behaves (or more accurately, is bounded) a certain way for all size inputs. So when I try and measure the general complexity of two solutions, I do so in as general a way as possible, and therefore try and consider all values of input size (i.e. n->infinity).

Finally, It allows theoreticians to group algorithms into the same class, irrespective of certain constant factors that may or may not change and may or may not be improved. This is helpful for, among other reasons, optimality proofs; finding that a problem is `omega(f(n))` is only useful if we consider algorithms in the complexity class of `O(f(n))`, irrespective of the constants.

Comment: I really disagree here. The “hidden constant” is *precisely* what allows to compare algorithms from the same class. You cannot seriously study algorithms “irrespective of the constants”.

Comment: @Sam, read what I wrote carefully, I'm not saying that sort of comparison is useless, just that it is *much* less relevant in general algorithm analysis, which is totally detached of implementation specifics. Indeed, when you deal with implementation it's important, but that doesn't sound like the situation the OP described. Although you're welcome to disagree with me.

Comment: I agree with pretty much everything here except for the assertion that the constants are "irrelevant".  From a typical programmer's point of view, they're highly relevant -- it's just that (as you say) there's no way to deal with them in a consistent way across architectures.  If someone wants to restrict themselves to a particular architecture where additions cost x and memory accesses cost y etc., then it's entirely possible to state running times exactly in terms of these quantities.  Just beware that e.g. a different motherboard or compiler version might change the expression.

Comment: @j_random, *sigh*. Why is everyone misunderstanding me? I never said they were irrelevant. I said they were irrelevant *when analysing algorithm complexity*. I wrote (obviously not clearly enough) that in implementation circumstances they **are** relevant...

Comment: I think the OP has only a vague understanding of the term "time complexity", while in your first sentence you're using it in its formal sense.  If you think about what "analysing time complexity" probably means to him/her, it might be clearer why saying constants are "irrelevant" to "analysing time complexity" is confusing/unhelpful.

Answer (score 5):

because while comparing very large values, (let's call it n)... n^2 will be higher then k*n for any k, where n->infinity.
this is of course true for any power/exponent of n.

**note** that in real life projects, you do make these optimizations and try to minimize the constants, but usually they are less siginificant then the degree of the polynom

Answer (score 3):

You only ignore constants when doing rough estimates. Most of the time, it's a valid simplification: when comparing two algorithms for large input dimensions, such as sorting an array, O(n log n) will eventually be faster or smaller than O(n²) no matter what.

However, when two algorithms have the same complexity, or when the expected dataset is so small that the asymptotic behaviour is not a valid real world scenario, then the constant is definitely important. For instance, a bubble sort implementation is likely to perform faster on an array of 3 or 4 values than quicksort.

Answer (score 2):

As the value of n grows in equation 6n^2 + 100n + 300 the **constant becomes of less relevance and we tend to ignore that**. See the following image

[image]

Picture taken from [Asymptotic Notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/asymptotic-notation) section at Khan Academy.