# Analysis algorithm Best, Worst and Average case

Tags: java, algorithm, replace, find

I want to know what is the best, worst ,and average case for find and replaceAll methods and the growth function which is basically the number of statement excuted in each case where the size of the array greater than zero in the following code

```
/**
 * Return index where value is found in array or -1 if not found.
 * @param array ints where value may be found
 * @param value int that may be in array
 * @return index where value is found or -1 if not found
 */
public static int find(int[] array, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Replace all occurrences of oldValue with newValue in array.
 * @param array ints where oldValue may be found
 * @param oldValue value to replace
 * @param newValue new value
 */
public static void replaceAll(int[] array, int oldValue, int newValue) {
    int index = find(array, oldValue);
    while (index > -1) {
        array[index] = newValue;
        index = find(array, oldValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the best worst and average case is for each of your two methods and why do you think that?

Comment: For find():1- best case if the element in the first index of the array2- Worst case: if the element does not exist in the array. 3- average: if the element in the middile of the array. That is what I was thinking about. I want to find also the growth function

Comment: Edit your question to include that and what "growth function" are you trying to find?

Answer (score 0):

**This is for the find(...) method**

You know the best and worst case quite easily:

The best case is when the element you are searching for is the first element in the array. In that case, it takes only 1 iteration to find your element, `O(1)` constant time.

Similarly, the worst case is when the element you are searching for does not exist in the array, so you iterate over the entire array just to find nothing. In that case, it takes n iterations (where n is the size of the array), `O(n)` linear time.

The worst case is determined quite easily most of the time. You can simply look at nested loops. If you have `x` amount of nested loops, where all the loops iterate over the array in linear time, then your time complexity is O(n^x). So in replaceAll(...), you have 2 nested loops (`while` and `for` from your `find(...)` method) meaning the complexity is `O(n^2)` worst case for `replaceAll(...)`

For the average case:

I wrote a test for your `find(...)` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int iterationsTotal = 0;
    int timesTested = 100000;
    //Test 1000 times
    for(int i = 0; i < timesTested; i++) {

        int n = 100; //Array size to test 
        int[] array = new int[n];
        //Populate the array
        int j = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            array[j] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        }
        //You can search for any number, even 99. It will always result in 25 average.
        iterationsTotal += find(array, 5);
    }

    System.out.println(iterationsTotal / timesTested);

}
```

The code above tests your find function 100,000 times. It calculates the average iterations it took, which usually comes to ~25 everytime I run it. Using an array of size 100, an average of 25 iterations to find the element you are searching. That comes to `O(n/4)` where n = size of array, in this case 100. That is as good as O(n) ([Why to ignore the constants in computing the running time complexity of an Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242403/why-to-ignore-the-constants-in-computing-the-running-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)). So the average case would be O(n) for your `find(...)` algorithm. You can do the same for `replaceAll(...)`

Comment: Can you specify each case by itself

Comment: Ok, I've added the best / worst case

Comment: I am talking about the find method. I have edited to explain that, and also mentioned replaceAll's worst case time complexity.

Comment: find() Method: best case: we will have 3 statement executed Worst case:3n+2 statement average statement: is (3n/2)+3 statements. Is That Correct

Comment: You don't have to care about 3 statements. What you care about is the loop, that's what takes longest. Also, you don't write `O(3n+2)` The 3 and 2 are insignificant. The notable part of that expression is n, which can get very large depending on the size of your array. That expression's value will only ever get large when n is large. Therefore, we only write `O(n)` At the end of the day, the time complexity is linearly dependent on n. 3 and 2 will only increase it so much.

Comment: I know that, but when finding the complexity function, you need to put the show the function in mathematical format.

Answer (score 0):

**Find**

- At best we find the desired sequence in the first spot so: **Ω(1)**
- At worst we find the desired sequence last so: **O(n)**
- The **Average: Θ(n)**

**ReplaceAll**

- This will at worst be **O(n^2)** because it needs to search through all of the characters to find desired replacements.

**Growth Function?**

- There wasn't any growth method in the code above so I'll provide you with the time complexity for copying an array. **All cases** are linear **O(n)**.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: ReplaceAll worst case should be O(n^2).

Comment: This is not true. If you have an array like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and you want to replace `1` with `2`, this will run in __O(n^2)__. Since it will loop again from the start at each replacement

Comment: The general rule of thumb is when you have nested loops, the time complexity for the worst case will be O(n^2)

Comment: Oh goodness. I thought he was referring to Java's implementation of replaceAll. I believe it is O(n) right?

Comment: By The growth function, I mean how may statements is executed at each case

Comment: @OsamaNatouf where is your growth function?

Comment: I need to find the growth function. which is basically, The number of statement executed in each case

Comment: I think O(n^2) is the growth.

Comment: O(n^2)  for replaceAll() method correct. but actually  the complexity function should be mathematical form.

Answer (score 0):

## Your runtime is in `O(n^2)`

- **Best case**: The array contains exactly one item that's equal to the value you want to replace. This item is also the first item in your array. Runs in `n` iterations
- **Worst case**: All items in your array are equal to the value you want to replace. This will run in `n^2` iterations

## A simple optimization to make it in `O(n)`

If you want to make it in `O(n)`, you need to pass the start index when using `find` so you don't have to repeatedly search from the start of your array

```
public static int find(int[] array, int value, int start) {
    for (int i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void replaceAll(int[] array, int oldValue, int newValue) {
    int index = find(array, oldValue);
    while (index > -1) {
        array[index] = newValue;
        index = find(array, oldValue, index);
    }
}
```