# What do the constant factors in a time complexity equation represent?

Tags: algorithm

all.

I'm taking a Coursera course on data structures and algorithms to prep myself for my upcoming semester which has a data structures and algorithms course. In my study I'm currently on the topic of algorithm analysis. This lead to me going down a rabbit hole and reading other resources. In one of those resources they have a time complexity equation for Insertion-Sort:
[image: Figure 1]

My question is what exactly do the constant factors in the equation (C_1, C_2, C_3, etc.) represent? My understanding is they represent the run time to execute a specific line (so C_2 represents the time it takes to execute key = A[j]. This is based on the understanding that the equation represents time complexity, and time complexity is a measurement of the change in runtime as input size changes (Figure 2 and Figure 3 below):
[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]

Of course, you can see in the same sentence the authors of *Introduction to Algorithms* say C_i is a measurement of steps. Then in the book *A Common-Sense Guide to Data Structures and Algorithms, Second Edition* the author says this:

> If you take away just one thing from this book, let it be this: when we measure
> how “fast” an operation takes, we do not refer to how fast the operation takes
> in terms of pure time, but instead in how many steps it takes.
> We’ve actually seen this earlier in the context of printing the even numbers
> from 2 to 100. The second version of that function was faster because it took
> half as many steps as the first version did.

> Why do we measure code’s speed in terms of steps?
> We do this because we can never say definitively that any operation takes,
> say, five seconds. While a piece of code may take five seconds on a particular
> computer, that same piece of code may take longer on an older piece of
> hardware. For that matter, that same code might run much faster on the
> supercomputers of tomorrow. Measuring the speed of an operation in terms
> of time is undependable, since the time will always change depending on the
> hardware it is run on.

> However, we can measure the speed of an operation in terms of how many
> computational steps it takes. If Operation A takes 5 steps, and Operation B
> takes 500 steps, we can assume that Operation A will always be faster than
> Operation B on all pieces of hardware. Measuring the number of steps is,
> therefore, the key to analyzing the speed of an operation.

> Measuring the speed of an operation is also known as measuring its time
> complexity. Throughout this book, I’ll use the terms speed, time complexity,
> efficiency, performance, and runtime interchangeably. They all refer to the
> number of steps a given operation takes.

The Wikipedia page for [Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) says:

> In computer science, the time complexity is the computational complexity that describes the amount of computer time it takes to run an algorithm. Time complexity is commonly estimated by counting the number of elementary operations performed by the algorithm, supposing that each elementary operation takes a fixed amount of time to perform.

So there seems to be a dual definition and understanding of time complexity and what the equation represents. I see that intrinsically, the more steps an algorithm takes the longer it's going to take. I also understand that it's usually very difficult or impossible to measure the exact running time of an algorithm and therefor may be efficacious to count the number of steps an algorithm takes.

That said, I'm having a difficult time fulling making this connection between the two, and ultimately what those constant factors in the equation represent. If they do represent running time, why are they then counted as just a constant and seem to be counted as 1 (1 for each time the line is executed)?

Hoping someone out there can help me understand what the equation represents, the connection between runtime and steps, etc.

I appreciate you taking the time to read this and for your help.

Comment: Note, I'm not sure if you want to understand this in a practical sense, if so, the runtime constants can be just as important (or sometimes more important) than the asymptotic scaling (since a program that runs a constant 10^6 times faster is MUCH faster than the reference program, even if the reference program has good asymptotic scaling.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the constants represent the steps that must be taken to execute each line. The equation represents the number of all steps.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are just...constants! They represent the specific time each operation on average takes to be executed (consider that in reality every operation is a set of operations in [Machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)), so every different operation has a different running time but if the constants are all of similar sizes the difference between them is not always that important (every programming languages has his features so something really fast in one can be somewhat slow in another, [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) for example there are performanceTips for python).

The focus of the analysis is on **how many** times the operations are executed.  Big O complexity considers the limiting behaviour so constants are not important, just the 'speed' of the functions involved ( a**n*^2+b**n* is always O(*n*^2) for every constants a and b).

Anyway some optimization can be useless because the different operations used cost more. Some instead can be really important if the two operations have constants with a big difference in execution time

Comment: So are they treated as constants because the operations in each specific line take roughly the same amount of time? So, for example, doing an assignment in line 2 might take roughly, say, 0.01 microseconds on average each time, though in reality it can vary slightly. So then we just say it takes 0.01 microseconds. 

It then seems once we disregard the constants, it changes from an equation of time to an equation of steps.

Comment: yes that is right, considering steps is usually more important

Comment: So now I understand what the constant factors are and that people tend to use terms interchangeably when they shouldn't and represent the equation as the number of steps when the equation isn't intended to represent that at all. It could be used to represent steps if the constant is 1, but it's still in units of time, ultimately. That said, what I'm confused about is why the constants don't matter. The difference between 1x and 10000x is huge, especially at large input values. They DO matter, so why are they being ignored?

Comment: Yes. However, *the rate of growth of both functions is same which is linear*. `y = x` and `y = 10000x` are both straight lines and they both have linear growth. Hence, they belong to same class of fucntions. In terms of asymptomatic notation, both functions belong to the class of `O(x)`. The constant still affects performance. However, we compare fucntions in terms of growth and not exact performance.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242403/why-to-ignore-the-constants-in-computing-the-running-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm#:~:text=4%20Answers&text=When%20analysing%20time%20complexity%20constants%20are%20difficult%20and%20irrelevant%20to%20calculate.&text=This%20isn't%20the%20case,environment%20it%20is%20the%20case.

Comment: @knvr in the case you mention the constants can't be ignored indeed you choose the first implementation! But in most cases they can be ignored because of similarity of constants. You need always to check that one of your lines hasn't a huge runtime in respect to the others. But if your operations are simple( they aren't call of other function of which you don't know the composition) then you can be sure enough that the big O analysis will give you the right result

Comment: @kvnr have you still doubts?