# Why the time complexity of linked list ( single linked list ) isn't n-1?

Tags: pointers, time, linked-list, time-complexity, singly-linked-list

My point is that when the pointer traverse in a linked list till **n-1** position he get the value of **nth** easily because as we know the address of **nth pointer** is at n-1th location. Hence, Time Complexity Must needed to be **n-1** instead of **n**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242403/why-to-ignore-the-constants-in-computing-the-running-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any Big O notation always describes an **upper** bound. this means although `n-1` would be more accurate to describe the complexity, it is still included in `O(n)`.
Secondly any constant factor (`-1`) is reduced from the equation, when describing a Big O complexity class, because for any decent large `n` any constant factor does not have any noticable influence on the result.
The same as any constant factor for the `n` is removed. `O(3n+5)` is the same complexity class as `O(n)`.

This both combined is the reason why you describe the complexity as `O(n)` and not `O(n-1)`, although it might technically still be correct and more accurate.