# Time complexity for nested loops with (1 <= n < n-1) range

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops

Quick question, can anyone please explain why
,`for 0 <= i < N` & `for 1 <= j < N-1`,
this nested for loops have a worst time complexity of Theta(N^2) and not Theta(N(N-2))? Isn't the fact that 0 and n value part of the its time complexity consideration when calculating for a nested for loop?

Comment: `N(N-2)` = `N^2 - 2N` We ignore `2N` as it grows slowly as compared to N^2. Hence O(N^2)

Comment: Check out the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242403/why-to-ignore-the-constants-in-computing-the-running-time-complexity-of-an-algor)

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating a time complexity we use the elements that grow the quickest.
So `O(n^2-2*n+1)=O(n^2)` and `O(log(n)+n) = O(n)`
Because the smallest part doesn't affect the complexity as much